# Why does my website load and show the bottom of the page first?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I can't seem to figure this one out, hopefully you guys can help.

When I load my website, it opens up at the bottom of the page. I thought it may be the smooth scroll js script or the parallax scroll js script causing this, but when I comment them out it still does the same.

My website still need lots of work on it but I have made my website live for a while so you can have a look. www.caico-studio.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you are implementing parallax scrolling.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your contact form has an element with "autofocus" attribute set.

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required="" autofocus="">
```

I actually did not know about this new attribute, there are a few sites explaining it, here for example; http://davidwalsh.name/autofocus

Comment: This was helps me a lot

Comment: Really helpfully Thanks! @hank

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have set focus to the input id=name.
If you want your webpage to load from the top remove the autofocus.

Answer (score 1):

I found this iframe code and deleted it which solved the problem for me.

`<iframe id="orderFrame" name="orderFrame"  src="#" style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;"></iframe>`

Check the iframes.